# Usage of TBitmapCodecManager in C++

Tags: c++, firemonkey

Please tell me how to use `TBitmapCodecManager` correctly in C++. My development environment is C++Builder 10.4 (Community Eddition) under FMX.

Here is the code of Delphi's `TBitmapCodecManager` sample rewritten for C++ for the purpose of PNG->ICO conversion.

However, a compile error occurs only on the last line:

> bcc32 error: [E2108] typedef 'TBitmapCodecManager' is used incorrectly.

```cpp
TMemoryStream * strm;
strm = new TMemoryStream;

TBitmapSurface * bmpss;
bmpss = new TBitmapSurface;

TBitmapCodecSaveParams * pm;
pm = new TBitmapCodecSaveParams;

pm-> Quality = 100;
bmpss-> Assign (Image1-> Bitmap);

TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream (strm, bmpss,'.ico', pm); // <-- error here
```

Could you please tell me the correct usage?

ref)[png / bmp-> ico by FMX (c ++) TBitmapCodecManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625627/png-bmp-ico-by-fmx-c-tbitmapcodecmanager)

Answer (score 1):

[`TBitmapCodecManager::SaveToStream()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream) is a [`class` method](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_Methods) in Delphi, which is translated to a `static` method in C++ (actually to [`__classmethod`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classmethod), which is a special kind of `static` in C++Builder). Unlike in Delphi, in C++ you need to use the `::` scope resolution operator to call a static method on a class type, not the `.` member access operator.

Also, C++ uses `""` for strings, and `''` for characters, unlike in Delphi which uses `''` for both.

Try this:

```cpp
TBitmapCodecManager::SaveToStream(strm, bmpss, _D(".ico"), pm);
```

Regarding the use of the `_D()` macro, this is explained in Embarcadero's documentation: [String Literals char16_t and wchar_t on macOS and iOS](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications#String_Literals_char16_t_and_wchar_t_on_macOS_and_iOS).